# How to create relationships in Django models

Tags: django, model, psql

I am not sure how I am suppose to represent my relationships correctly. Let's say I have 2 tables `User` and `Post`. For this example I will mix and match relationships between these 2 tables.

relationships

- 1st case

  > A user has `zero-to-many` posts and a post belongs to `one` user.

  - I looked at the `Many-to-One` relationships on `Django` documentation and decided I can maybe model this by doing the following...

  ```
  class User(models.Model):
    pass

  class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  ```

  - I read it as a `User` can have many post (zero or more).
  - A `Post` belongs to `one` (and only `one`) user.
- 2nd case

  > A `User` has `one-to-many` posts and a `Post` belongs to `one` user

  - This is almost identical to the first case but the difference here is that a `User` has `one-to-many` post vs. `zero-to-many`. I'm not sure how to model this. How do I tell my model `User` to own at least **1 or more posts but not zero**.

I may add more of the other relationships to this question if I need further clarification but for now would really like to know how this is suppose to work. The only thing I can think of is having a `null=True`, `blank=True` so that I am allowed to have nothing `zero-to-many` or leave the default so that I have `one-to-many`

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach is so popular one

```
class User(models.Model):
  pass

class Post(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this will guarantee no posts with out any user-related

Comment: And so does this mean that adding on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True will allow for 0 to many?